# How to make test case cover the statements inside pipe(map... using jest

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am using angular.

`Component code`

```
 httpClient.post(URL, requestBody)
   .pipe(map((result) => {
      serviceCall(result);
 }));
```

How to cover code inside pipe(map using Jest test case?

I wrote the jest test case like below but it's not covering the statements inside pipe

```
  spyOn(httpClient, 'post').and
    .returnValue(new Observable( observer => {
    observer.next([]);
  }));
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working"?
What doesn't work?

Comment: It's not covering the statements inside pipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code coverage doesn't mean anything when it comes to testing. It just shows that the engine read this part of code.

But if you want to cover it, you will have to test the end result of your stream.

```
spyOn(httpClient, 'post').and.returnValue(of({}));
spyOn(yourService, 'serviceCall').and.returnValue(of({ id: 1 });

myFunction().subscribe(res => expect(res.id).toEqual(1));
```

Comment: How can I access 'of' coming as following.. If I use like this - spyOn(_http, 'post').subscribe(res => {}); - Coming error '[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Spy'.' If I put - spyOn(_http, 'post').and.returnValue(of({})); - [ts] Cannot find name 'of'.

Comment: `import { of } from 'rxjs'`

Comment: If I use 'of' also not covering the lines inside pipe(map